# Обновить список при обновлении информации

Tags: javascript, angular2

У меня есть такой вот список с аккаунтами:

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Имя пользователя</th>
                <th>Имя</th>
                <th>Фамилия</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Роль</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let account of accounts">
                <td>{{ account.username }}</td>
                <td>{{ account.firstName }}</td>
                <td>{{ account.lastName }}</td>
                <td>{{ account.email }}</td>
                <td>{{ account.role.name }}</td>

                <td><button (click)="deleteAccount(account.username)" class="btn btn-danger">Удалить пользователя</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

И компонент, который отвечает за данную разметку:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'admin-allUsers-cmp',
    templateUrl: 'allUsers.component.html',
})
export class AllUsersComponent implements OnInit {
    paginator: Paginator;
    accounts: any[];
    allElementsCount: number;
    allPagesCount: number;

    constructor(private accountService: AccountService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.updateContent();
    }

    private updateContent(): void {
        this.accountService.getAllAccounts().then(accounts => {
            this.paginator = new Paginator(accounts, 10);

            this.accounts = this.paginator.getPageContent();
            this.allElementsCount = this.paginator.getElementsCount();
            this.allPagesCount = this.paginator.getPagesCount()
        });
    }

    next() {
        this.paginator.next();
        this.accounts = this.paginator.getPageContent();
    }

    before() {
        this.paginator.before();
        this.accounts = this.paginator.getPageContent();
    }


    deleteAccount(username: string): void {
        this.accountService.deleteAccount(username);
        this.updateContent();
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что при нажатии кнопки `Удалить пользователя` данные в списке не обновляются при попомощи метода `updateContent`. Самое интересно, что если хоть раз нажать `next()` или `before()`, то все начнет прекрасно обновляться при обновлении. Не могу понять такое поведение...

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef посмотри

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю проблема вот здесь:

```
this.accountService.deleteAccount(username);
this.updateContent();
```

Эти функции вызываются параллельно. С начала вы отправляете запрос на удаление, а следом запрос на получение списка. Бэкенд в момент получения запроса списка, скорее всего ещё не удалил значение.

Могу посоветовать вам использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
this.accountService.deleteAccount(username)
.toPromise()
.then(function(){
   this.updateContent();
})
```

Данная конструкция делает запрос на обновление списка, после выполнения запроса на удаление.

Comment: Да, действительно в этом и было дело. Спасибо!